# how normalize data for redux with normalizr if the data is in object not array format

Tags: redux, normalization, normalizr

I have a data of the following structure:

```
const originalData = {
    field1: {
        title: 'some title for field 1',
        subfields: {
            subfield1: { props: 'some props' },
            subfield2: { props: 'some other props' },
        }
    },
    field2: {
        title: 'some title for field 2',
        subfields: {
            subfield21: { props: 'some props for subfield 2.1.' },
            subfield22: { props: 'some other props for subfield 2.2' },
        }
    },
}
```

So both fields and subfields are not arrays as it would be normally, but objects.

I try to normalize the data for Redux splitting to two objects (`subfields` and `fields`) with normalizr, but that totally fails:

```
const subfield = new schema.Values('subfields')
const field = new schema.Entity('fields', { subfields: subfield });

const responseSchema = new schema.Values(field);
const normalizedData = normalize(originalData, responseSchema);
```

any advice would be great.